# Cannot define stable composer package

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I cannot tell whether it's my composer.json or its dependencies that cause composer to say the project is not stable.  Packagist points to the 1.0 branch at github.  The heart of composer.json appears below.

The only way I can get `composer create-project truckee/volunteer` to work is to add the argument `--stability=dev`.

#### Edit #2:

I am the owner of the package, so it is not being required by any other.

#### Edit:

Without argument the following error occurs:

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package
>   truckee/volunteer with stability stable.

Is it possible to make this stable?

#### composer.json

```
{
...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.11.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ],    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
        "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "1.0.@dev",
        "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.0.*",
        "jquery/jquery":  "1.11.*",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.0",
        "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~3.0"
    },
...
    "extra": {
         ...
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *that cause composer to say the project is not stable* Can you please add the output message in your question?

Comment: What package requires to install `truckee/volunteer`? Once you identify it, can you find a stable version number? And can you please post the full file? I can't test it.

Comment: @A.L No package requires it.  It's being offered as a project, i.e., an end-user application.

Comment: I don't understand the link between composer and `truckee/volunteer`. Why composer try to install it?

Comment: @A.L AFAIK, the best way for an end-user to install the project (as an application) is to `$ composer create-project truckee/volunteer`.  Or they could download the zip and `composer install`.

Comment: You should clarify that `truckee/volunteer` is *your* package. It seems that there is some confusion about that.

Comment: @JustinHoward: how did you guessed that he is the maintainer of the package?

Comment: @JustinHoward Ownership is now made clear.  Hadn't realized how useful knowing that would be!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer doesn't consider a git branch as stable. By default, all branches can be specified with the `<branch>-dev` version. However, those versions have a stability of "dev". In order to release a stable version, you need to **tag a commit**.

```
git tag -a v1.0.0 -m 'My release'
git push --tags
```

Now, once packagist reindexes, it will display a release `1.0.0` in the list. That release will be "stable". Now you can create your project with:

```
composer create-project truckee/volunteer
```

This will automatically get the latest tag in the repository.

See the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version) for more information on versions and tagging.

Comment: Many thanks.  It had not been clear until just now that this was true.  I can now change my instructions.